# Why my javascript src doesn't work when I'm not in the root folder?

Tags: javascript, typescript, src

I'm a beginner in javascript, just learning.
I had an issue with the  tag and the "src" command.
When I run my html file from the root directory it works, but it doesn't work when I'm using another folder, for example a folder in the desktop... I tried and searched all that came to my mind, but no clue.

I'm using Sublime Text in UbuntuMate with Firefox browser.

This is the HTML file.`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>

    <script scr="myscript.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is the "myscript.js" file (it's in the same folder)

`alert('hello hello pls work');`

know this is a silly question but I just wanna know if is a code issue or a some kind of permission/system issue.
Thanks a lot.

I tried to use the full path, the "./" and another locations inside the root directory, and searched in the internet.

Comment: `scr` vs `src` maybe?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The only mistake I see is that you put `scr` instead of `src` in your `<script>` tag.  I've tested it, making no changes other than that, and it works; it's just a little easy slip-up. 

This is the line corrected:
`<script src="myscript.js"></script>`

Comment: This question should be flagged as a typo.

Comment: @Andy, I'm fairly new to this site, but doesn't it make more sense to just actually tell someone what their typo was though?

Comment: The comment under the question is doing exactly that and that is where that belongs. If it was not there, you have enough rep to comment

Comment: When the question is answered, it is harder to delete it